# How to always execute a command when a shell script function finishes?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script, zsh

I need to write a `zsh` function with multiple exit points and execute the same clean-up command at every one of them:

```sh
function foo {
    if ... ; then
        ...
        run_cleanup
        return
    elif ... ; then
        some_command || (run_cleanup ; return 1)
    else
        ...
    fi
    ...
    run_cleanup
}
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating `run_cleanup` at every exit point (which is very error-prone)?

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to use `trap EXIT`, which registers a clean-up action to be run automatically when the function finishes:

```sh
function foo {
    trap run_cleanup EXIT
    if ... ; then
        ...
        return
    elif ... ; then
        some_command || return 1
    else
        ...
    fi
    ...
}
```

Note that using `trap ... EXIT` in functions is [`zsh`-specific](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins):

> If sig is `0` or `EXIT` and the trap statement is executed inside the body of a function, then the command arg is executed after the function completes.
> ...
> If sig is `0` or `EXIT` and the trap statement is not executed inside the body of a function, then the command arg is executed when the shell terminates.

In [`bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) the command is `trap ... RETURN`.

> If a *sigspec* is `EXIT` (0) the command arg is executed on exit from the shell ... If a *sigspec* is `RETURN`, the command *arg* is executed each time a shell function or a script executed with the `.` or `source` builtins finishes executing.